# Эффективный способ найти кол-во чисел с непростым кол-вом делителей

Tags: java, алгоритм, олимпиада, простые-числа

Алгоритмическая задачка:
найти на заданном диапазоне количество чисел, которые либо простые, либо у которых число делителей не является простым числом.

Тестовые примеры:

Для интервала [3, 7] результат равен 4

Для интервала [77, 1010] результат равен 924

мое решение умирает на промежутке [1000;100000000000l]  по времени. Есть мысли как решать?

```java
    class Finder {
    private int lastDivNumber = 0;
    private int currentDivCounter = 0;

    public Finder() {
    }

    private boolean isSimple(long number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0 && number != 2) {
            lastDivNumber = 2;
            ++currentDivCounter;
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i+=2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                lastDivNumber = i;
                ++currentDivCounter;
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean isCountSimple(long number) {
        currentDivCounter += 2;
        for(int i = lastDivNumber + 1; i<= number / 2; ++i) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                ++currentDivCounter;
            }
        }
        return isSimple(currentDivCounter);
    }


    public int getCountInterestNumbers(long left, long right) {
        int countResult = 0;

        for (long number = left; number <= right; ++number) {
            currentDivCounter = 0;
            lastDivNumber = 0;

            if (isSimple(number)) {
                ++countResult;
            } else {
                if (!isCountSimple(number)) {
                    ++countResult;
                }
            }
        }
        return countResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сразу на старте генерируйте список простых чисел в максимальном диапазоне, и потом используйте его. Это первое. И второе - просто подумайте, какие числа имеют непростое количество делителей... для начала - хотя бы нечётное, а там пойдёт.

Comment: Откуда задача? URL не дадите? Просто есть некоторые мысли, но озвучивать их, не протестировав, не хочется :)

Comment: https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=2070

Comment: Очевидно, что это все простые числа плюс квадраты, у которых число делителей - простое. По-моему, самое сложное - посчитать число простых чисел, а квадратов вроде бы немного.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь опытом человечества - возьмите готовую таблицу простых чисел. Например, [список первых 50 миллионов простых чисел](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).

Этого вам хватит, чтобы быстро раскладывать на множители числа до 965211250482432409, то есть почти достаточно, чтобы просеять почти все целые числа, представимые типом `long` в java.

В общем случае задача разложения на множители эффективного решения не имеет.

Если таблицы простых чисел вас не устраивают, то есть второй источник ускорения счёта - взять [тест Миллера-Рабина](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-3-miller-rabin/), продвинутый метод проверки простоты чисел, которым пользуются в криптографии. ИМХО, после миллиона он будет быстрее, чем перебор делителей до квадратного корня.

**Число делителей**

Число делителей нужно искать не перебором, а через простые делители. Если `n=p1*p2*p3`, то у него 8 делителей: `1, p1,  p2, p3, p1*p2, p1*p3, p2*p3, p1*p2*p3`

Если у числа `n` один из делителей входит в какой-нибудь степени, то подсчёт чутка усложняется. Обозначим число делителей `n` как `ndiv(n)`.
Тогда:

- `ndiv(1) = 1`
- `ndiv(p) = 2`
- `ndiv(p*(p1*p2*...*pn)) = 2*ndiv(p1*...*pn)`
- `ndiv(p^a*(p1*...*pn)) = (a+1)*ndiv(p1*...*pn)`

В общем случае, пусть `n = p^a * m`, где `m` не делится на `p`. Тогда `ndiv(n) = (a+1) * ndiv(m)`

Видно невооруженным глазом, что `ndiv(n)` будет простым числом тогда и только тогда, когда `n = p^a` и `a+1` - простое число. Только такие числа вам нужно отбрасывать при рассмотрении.

**Итого**

Для максимальной производительности вам нужно:

1. Проверить, является ли число результатом возведения простого числа в степень 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 36 (нужно проверить отдельный случай для 2 - там надо перебирать до степени 60)

   Этот шаг можно значительно ускорить, если заранее посчитать степени для малых простых чисел.
2. Для чисел больше миллиона проверять простоту тестом Миллера Рабина. Он вам потребуется только при проверке чисел вида `p^2` при `p` больше миллиона, то есть для чисел больше чем `10^12`. Если таких чисел в интервале нет, то достаточно проверять решетом по [простым числам до 1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers#The_first_1000_prime_numbers).

Comment: мое предположение - что я упираюсь в лимит по времени из за проверки на простоту кол-ва делителей.

Comment: @KonstantinMorozov Да, это так. Я обновил ответ - добавил в него алгоритм проверки того, что число делителей является простым числом.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: можно не умножать простые, а брать корень нужной степени. Там достаточно малая погрешность получается в double

Comment: В помощь - количество делителей, если степени простых делителей p,q,r... есть `(p+1)*(q+1)*(r+1)...`

Comment: Простите, а зачем проверять простоту больших чисел? Нам же нужно только отбросить степени простых.

Comment: @defaultlocale в общем случае. В задаче же не оговорены ограничения на размер чисел? Пользователь имеет право ввести что угодно. Например, `n=340282366920938461286658806734041124249`. Оставим за скобками, что это число тоже надо проверить на простоту. Нетрудно установить, что оно равно `q*q` где `q=18446744073709551557`. Если `q` составное, то `n` подходит, число делителей будет составным. А если нет - то `n` не подходит. Лобовой перебор на моем core i7 за 12 секунд установил, что `q` - простое. А тест Миллера Рабина сделал это за несколько микросекунд.

Comment: @PakUula Все-таки не совсем понял. Речь же идет о диапазоне чисел. Как проверка на простоту большого числа поможет работать с диапазоном? И да, автор дал ссылку на задачу в комментариях к вопросу, ограничения границ диапазона L<R<10^12

Comment: @defaultlocale да, ограничение на размер чисел я проглядел. При числах до 10^12 разложение на множители можно делать грубой силой. Ваше решение я увидел. При заданных ограничениях действовать от списка простых чисел действительно проще, чем извлекать корни и проверять их на простоту.

Answer (score 4):

Ваше решение не проходит уже потому что в нем перебираются все числа 2 до 10^12. Даже без каких-либо операций внутри цикла такой перебор не выполнится за 2 секунды.

Нужно пересматривать подход.

### Числа Аси

С числами, интересными Коле все ясно, рассмотрим какие числа интересны Асе.

Количество делителей числа вида  p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>...p<sub>N</sub><sup>k<sub>N</sub></sup> равно (k<sub>1</sub>+1)*(k<sub>1</sub>+1)*...*(k<sub>N</sub>+1). Получается, что если у числа есть два разных простых делителя, то количество его делителей не будет простым. Отсюда вывод, что Асе интересны только числа вида p<sup>k</sup>, причем такие, что (k+1) — простое число. Этот вывод уже ранее показал [@Pak Uula](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/371023/pak-uula) в соседнем ответе.

### Группы чисел

Зная это, рассмотрим какие числа встречаются в нашем диапазоне:

1. Простые числа — они интересны и Коле и Асе.
2. Числа вида p<sup>k</sup>, где p и (k+1) — простые числа, причем k>1. Такие числа интересны только Асе.
3. Остальные числа (имеющие несколько простых множителей, либо «неподходящие» степени простых) — неинтересны обоим.

Нам нужно подсчитать количество чисел первого и третьего вида. Но проще сделать наоборот: рассчитать количество чисел второго вида и вычесть их из общего количества (R-L+1).

### Алгоритм

Задача сводится к тому чтобы подсчитать в диапазоне числа вида p<sup>k</sup>, где p и (k+1) — простые числа, причем k>1. Т.к. таких чисел относительно немного, то проще не проверять все числа в диапазоне, а наоборот вычислять все возможные степени и считать те, которые попадают в диапазон.

По шагам:

- Сгенерируем простые числа до 1000000 (больше нам не понадобится). Это можно сделать решетом Эратосфена.
- Перебираем степени k. Пробегаем по простым числам, начиная с трех, от каждого отнимаем единицу и выполняем следующие действия:

  - Перебираем основания p. Пробегаем по простым числам, каждое возводим в степень k.
  - Если полученное значение попадает в диапазон увеличиваем счетчик.
  - Если же оно больше R, то выходим из цикла перебора p.
  - Если обнаружилось, что для степени k нет ни одного p такого что p<sup>k</sup><=R, то выходим из цикла перебора k тоже.
- В результате получится число A — количество чисел в диапазоне, которые интересны только Асе. Ответом же для нашей задачи будет число: R-L+1-A.

Если не считать решето, то сложность у этого алгоритма C*log(R), где C — количество простых чисел p, таких что p*p<=R.